# With a Gigabyte motherboard where I have flashed the BIOS, if I reset the CMOS will it also reset the BIOS to default?

Tags: motherboard, bios, desktop, cmos, cd

I have a GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-DH3 motherboard.  In March 2020 I flashed the BIOS in order to make it compatible with a Windforce graphics card.

This caused Windows 7 to think my computer was new and it was running a pirated copy.  I no longer have the product key, so I am now installing a new OEM copy of Windows 10 (cd) on a new SSD.  At the moment, the only hardware is this new SSD and the CD-ROM drive (I will hook up a Raid 0 HDD array and an old HDD with files from last build when tge OS is installed).

But the BIOS is giving me a "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device" error.  I can see the drive in the BIOS so I don't think it's a hardware problem.  I'm running Legacy and tried UEFI once also.

At this point, I'm suspecting that I need to clear the CMOS to get the motherboard to see the CD and get OS installation, but it's unclear to me if this will also factory reset the BIOS, thereby losing the flash that enabled the graphics card that chased the cat that killed the rat that lived in the house that I built.

Will resetting CMOS also reset the BIOS?

Comment: Clearing cmos will not revert the bios version.

Comment: Thank you.  If you answer the question I will gladly accept.

Comment: That board had a dual bios, the main bios which you flashed, and a backup bios, you should be able to revert it in the bios somewhere. See page 66>>>>https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z77x-d3h_e.pdf

Comment: Enter the bios and select Load Defaults, this should get it booting again.